# HTML Form. When to use named frame in target attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In HTML Form  we can set target attribute to various values: `_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename`.

But what is use case of named frame in target attribute?

Answer (score 1):

This is relevant if you are using [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) for your page layout, however frames are rarely used these days.

Comment: Frames are no longer supported in HTML5 so this particular use of framename should be considered deprecated. It should still work with iframes however.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you can specify the name of an iframe that you want the response to be displayed in.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp#

(from docs) Note: Frames and framesets are not supported in HTML5, so the _parent, _top and framename values are now mostly used with iframes.